# error: snap “package” has “install-snap” change in progress

Tags: linux, manjaro

I am using linux manjaro and i got this error while installing spotify.
[image]

**Tried - sudo snap remove spotify but it's says that spotify is not istalled.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait for a few minutes. Then run `sudo snap remove spotify` to remove **spotify** snap from your machine. Then again you can run `sudo snap install spotify` to install the **spotify** snap in your machine. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Run `snap changes` in console to watch if task is still `Doing`. In my case I see this:

```
ID   Status  Spawn               Ready               Summary
1    Done    2020-12-22          2020-12-22          Initialize system state
2    Error   today at 00:50 CET  today at 01:01 CET  Install "intellij-idea-community" snap
3    Done    today at 00:50 CET  today at 00:50 CET  Initialize device
4    Doing   today at 09:43 CET  -                   Install "intellij-idea-community" snap
```

If I use `snap watch 4` I can see the progress of the task in real time.

So the task I cancelled manually because it was late has been resumed automatically, I only have to wait.